# Why do I have to escape a "dot" twice?

Tags: shell-script, grep, regular-expression, quoting, escape-characters

I know that we can escape a special character like `*(){}$` with `\` so as to be considered literals.
For example `\*` or `\$`

But in case of `.` I have to do it twice, like `\\.` otherwise it is considered special character. Example:

```
man gcc | grep \\.
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Can you give the case that you have to escape twice?

Comment: `man bash|grep \\.` could be a example.

Comment: More precisely, you do not escape dot twice, you escape the escape character so that it gets passed to grep

Comment: You could use quotation marks to avoid escaping backslash characters: `man gcc | grep '\.'`.

Comment: I strongly prefer @LeonidBeschastny's suggestion because of how much clearer it is what's going on

Comment: That depends on what shell will be interpreting that code. See also [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Generally, you only have to escape one time to make special character considered literal. Sometime you have to do it twice, because your pattern is used by more than one program.

Let's discuss your example:

```
man gcc | grep \\.
```

This command is interpreted by two programs, the `bash` interpreter and `grep`. The first escape causes `bash` to know `\` is literal, so the second is passed for `grep`.

If you escape only one time, `\.`, `bash` will know this dot is literal, and pass `.` to `grep`. When `grep` see this `.`, it thinks the dot is special character, not literal`.`

If you escape twice, `bash` will pass the pattern `\.` to `grep`. Now `grep` knows that it is a literal dot.

Comment: :So,Does the escape character for dot depends on the number of pipes we use?.For example cmd | cmd | cmd | cmd \\\\. Is that correct????

Comment: @Thushi: No. This has nothing to do with the fact that you are using a (or several) pipe characters, but applies even for `grep \\. my_file`. The commandline is interpreted by the shell, using the first `\ ` to escape the second one, so one `\ ` is passed literally to grep. The dot `.` is not special to the shell, so it is passed verbatim anyway. Grep then reads the (single) `\ ` and uses it to escape the dot `.`.

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann: Yes.That's true.Checked it.Thanks :)

Comment: I believe the answer is somewhat incorrect in that it says "The first escape causes bash knows . is literal, the second is for grep.". Actually, the first escape lets bash know that \ is leteral, and pass \. to grep.

Comment: @Gnouc I don't think it has. `echo .` in the bash just... echoes bach `.` character.

Comment: @Cthulhu: Oh, my bad, updated.

Comment: @Emmanuel: After Cthulhu's comment, see above.

Comment: @gnouc Ok sorry, I missed it

Answer (score 0):

To prevent bash from trying to interpret your arguments, enclose them in quotes

```
man gcc | grep "\."
```

Comment: In general, it would be better to use single quotes as backslash is still special within double quotes (though not when followed by `.`) in Bourne-like shells. Or use `grep -F .`. BTW, the OP made no mention of the `bash` shell. Not all shells treat backslash or `"..."` as quoting operators. `rc` doesn't for instance (same comment applies to the accepted answer).