# Strange behaviour of "ls -a | grep ^\."

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I wanted to list the content of a pwd and display only file starting with dot.
I tried `ls -a | grep ^\.` but I cannot figure out why the output contains also the files which do not start with dot. For example:

```
Pictures
.pip
.pki
.profile
projects
Public
```

I know that I can achieve what I want with `ls -ld .*` I am just curious about this behaviour of grep which I can't explain.

Comment: See also: [Why do I have to escape a “dot” twice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144752)

Comment: Why not just `ls -d .*` to list all files starting with `.`?

Comment: A cautionary note: Never pipe the output of ls into another command. Use find instead. ls has way too many ideosyncrasies to be trusted. See: Pitfall 1 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls - it made #1! The rest of the site is great too.

Answer (score 20):

Quote the argument to `grep`, thus `ls -a | grep '^\.'`

The reason for this is that the shell handles `\.` and turns it back into plain `.`, which `grep` then treats as a single-character wildcard. If in doubt, always quote a string that contains (or might contain) a character that's special to the shell.

Comment: Why does shell ignore \?

Comment: \ is an escape sequence which makes the shell to treat the following character as a  literal one. In this `grep ^\\.`, \\ is treated by the shell as a single backslash and again the grep treats  single backslash followed by the dot as literal dot.

Answer (score 11):

You need to put the grep regex inside quotes.

```
ls -a | grep '^\.'
```

Note: [Don't parse the output of `ls` command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Why is it bad to parse the output of ls ?

Comment: From the link:  In its default mode, if standard output isn't a terminal, ls separates filenames with newlines. This is fine until you have a file with a newline in its name.

Comment: @Michael Durrant: I'd suggest that allowing newlines in filenames is a major system bug.

Comment: @jamesqf - see [newlines in filenames](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23163) (especially _sml_'s answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you execute cmd **ls -a | grep ^\.** then grep do not consider "\" as a special character and meaning of "." do not get escaped.

When we use cmd **ls -a | grep "^\."** then grep considers "\" as a special character and meaning of "." gets escaped. It will give you a result as expected.

If you want to use grep cmd without quotes then you should escape "\" character also.
You can have expected result without double quotes by following command.
**ls -a | grep ^\\.**

For details about meaning of special characters in Regex, refer following link.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html